# Is there an approach to explain mirror reflection different than Feynman's?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, reflection, path-integral

In "The Strange Theory of Light and Matter" Richard Feynman uses a "stopwatch" to time the photon as it moves. For each photon path, the final direction of the hand is considered as a "vector", which is a rather strange step. Then all possible "vectors" are combined to end up with a "probability", which is is another strange step.
All this appears as a simplified way to make the concepts of QED accessible to a non-expert audience like me. What are the more formal ways to describe this theory?

Comment: Feynman is essentially describing the [path integral formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) of quantum mechanics

Comment: Most textbooks on optics have an alternative.

Comment: @By Symmetry Thanks for redirecting me toward the founding principles.

Comment: @ ProfRob You are refering to textbooks on optics. Does it means that QED deals specifically with the optic domain?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/684719/2451